# Single Sign-on architecture with Django and Azure

Tags: django, azure, single-sign-on

I have 3 applications developed with Django Framework and i need to centralize authentification through Single Sign-On (SSO) with Azure AD.

My questions are the following :

- What is the best architecture to implement the solution?
- Which libraries should i use ?

(i'll be gratefull if usefull tutorials are attached :p)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has an official guide for that: [Enable user sign-in to your Django web app using Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/msid-django-web-app-sign-in/)